# 03 chevy impala trasmission will not go forward nor backwards

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, impala

I have always checked the trans fluids and one day as i was heading out i started to give it gas and it went for a bit than as i pushed more on the gas...it would not go forward anymore. i than put it in park and back in drive again and still no movement forward. Had an idea it might be my tranny so i put it in reverse...it did go backwards but than after a while as i started to back up more and i noticed as i pushed more on the gas...It would go anywhere either....could it be something els or do i face it that i do need a new tranny for my car???(ughhh!!!)

Comment: Are you saying that the fluid level is ok?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a few transmissions crap out, need to be replaced. Sounds like you now have one also. I assume you are not changing it yourself so whatever shop you take it to will be able to verify this for you. Final diagnosis will have to be with mechanic who actually looks at your car.